# Using intransitive verbs with passive voice

Tags: word-usage

I saw the definiton of *apply* on [cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/apply) and I saw two example sentences under more exapmles section of the second definition that defines the verb as intransitive:

> apply *(definition)* [I]: (especially of rules or laws) to have a connection or be important
>  
>  (example 1) The legislation must be applied irrespective of someone's ethnic origins.
>  (example 2) It is intended that these guidelines should be applied flexibly and pragmatically.

I am a bit confused with the examples. Can we use intransitive verbs as passive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use intransitive verbs in passive voice. The object in active voice becomes the patient in passive voice: a patient is required to form a passive voice sentence, and an intransitive verb has no object.

I think that the Cambridge Dictionary has made a little mistake. The two examples that you quote actually relate to this meaning:

> apply [T] to make use of something or use it for a practical purpose

Consider these sentences, using the two different meanings: it is clear that only the second meaning makes sense.

> The legislation must be **important** irrespective of someone's ethnic origins.
>   It is intended that these guidelines should be **important** flexibly and pragmatically.
>
> The legislation must be **used** irrespective of someone's ethnic origins.
>   It is intended that these guidelines should be **used** flexibly and pragmatically.